# Entity Framework Core Error Handling

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.0 and EF Core 2.0.

I am trying to catch errors in the Web API to log them to my database. When I do so, it seems to mess up either the datareader (not closing) or the db context. I am dependency injecting the db context into the controller.

```
public class ClientsController : Controller
{
    private VsNetTestContext moDbContext;

    public ClientsController(VsNetTestContext dbContext)
    {
        moDbContext = dbContext;
        if (GlobalExceptionHandler.DbContext == null)
        {
            GlobalExceptionHandler.DbContext = moDbContext;
        }
    }
```

GlobalExceptionHandler is a singleton class for tracking exceptions in the back end.

Here is an example get:

```
// GET api/clients/5/ABC
[HttpGet("{nav}/{id}")]
public IActionResult Get(string nav, string id)
{
    try
    {
        var loAction = new SqlParameter("action", nav);
        var loClientID = new SqlParameter("client_id", (object)id ?? DBNull.Value);
        var loResult = moDbContext.client.FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.GetClientRecord @action, @client_id", loAction, loClientID).SingleOrDefault<client>();
        return new ObjectResult(loResult);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
        return new ObjectResult(GlobalExceptionHandler.Log(ex, "UpdateClientRecord"));
    }
}
```

I'm catching the error and setting the response status to 500 so that I can log the error in my database in the Log method of my GlobalExceptionHandler:

```
public static void Log()
{
    //Writes exception data to the database
    try
    {
        if (DbContext == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        var lcolParams = new List<SqlParameter>();
        lcolParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@err_title", mcErrTitle));
        lcolParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@err_message", mcErrMsg));
        lcolParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@err_description", mcErrDescription));
        lcolParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@app_name", "VsNetTest"));
        lcolParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@app_version", "1.0"));
        DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("dbo.LogApplicationError @err_title, @err_message, @err_description, @app_name, @app_version", lcolParams.ToArray());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //ignore
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Log Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I forced an error in the Get by adding a property to the client model that does not exist in the query result (another pain point), but it throws an exception when executing the ExecuteSqlCommand.  Below is the debug output:

```
Application Insights Telemetry(unconfigured): { "name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2017-09-21T11:56:49.4156731Z","tags":{ "ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.1.1","ai.internal.nodeName":"CTAPLAPTOP4","ai.operation.id":"a52ef379-4f366ebbd2a82b55","ai.operation.name":"GET Clients/Get [id/nav]","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"CTAPLAPTOP4","ai.operation.parentId":"|a52ef379-4f366ebbd2a82b55.","ai.location.ip":"127.0.0.1"},"data":{ "baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{ "ver":2,"message":"Executed DbCommand (59ms) [Parameters=[action='?' (Size = 1), client_id='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']\r\nEXECUTE dbo.GetClientRecord @action, @client_id","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{ "DeveloperMode":"true","CategoryName":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command","{OriginalFormat}":"Executed DbCommand ({elapsed}ms) [Parameters=[{parameters}], CommandType='{commandType}', CommandTimeout='{commandTimeout}']{newLine}{commandText}","commandType":"Text","elapsed":"59","commandText":"EXECUTE dbo.GetClientRecord @action, @client_id","commandTimeout":"30","parameters":"action='?' (Size = 1), client_id='?'","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development"} } } }
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand(59ms) [Parameters=[action='?' (Size = 1), client_id='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
EXECUTE dbo.GetClientRecord @action, @client_id
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): { "name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Exception","time":"2017-09-21T11:56:49.4890679Z","tags":{ "ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.1.1","ai.internal.nodeName":"CTAPLAPTOP4","ai.operation.id":"a52ef379-4f366ebbd2a82b55","ai.operation.name":"GET Clients/Get [id/nav]","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"CTAPLAPTOP4","ai.operation.parentId":"|a52ef379-4f366ebbd2a82b55.","ai.location.ip":"127.0.0.1"},"data":{ "baseType":"ExceptionData","baseData":{ "ver":2,"properties":{ "DeveloperMode":"true","CategoryName":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query","error":"System.InvalidOperationException: The required column 'extra_field' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Sql.Internal.FromSqlNonComposedQuerySqlGenerator.CreateValueBufferFactory(IRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory relationalValueBufferFactoryFactory, DbDataReader dataReader)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ShaperCommandContext.<NotifyReaderCreated>b__11_0(FactoryAndReader s)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.NonCapturingLazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized[TParam,TValue](TValue& target, TParam param, Func`2 valueFactory)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ShaperCommandContext.NotifyReaderCreated(DbDataReader dataReader)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(Boolean buffer)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<CompileQueryCore>b__0(QueryContext qc)","{OriginalFormat}":"An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query for context type '{contextType}'.{newline}{error}","Exception":"System.InvalidOperationException: The required column 'extra_field' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Sql.Internal.FromSqlNonComposedQuerySqlGenerator.CreateValueBufferFactory(IRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory relationalValueBufferFactoryFactory, DbDataReader dataReader)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ShaperCommandContext.<NotifyReaderCreated>b__11_0(FactoryAndReader s)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.NonCapturingLazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized[TParam,TValue](TValue& target, TParam param, Func`2 valueFactory)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ShaperCommandContext.NotifyReaderCreated(DbDataReader dataReader)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(Boolean buffer)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<CompileQueryCore>b__0(QueryContext qc)","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","contextType":"WebApiAureliaCli.Models.VsNetTestContext"},"exceptions":[{"id":23492147,"typeName":"System.InvalidOperationException","message":"An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query for context type 'WebApiAureliaCli.Models.VsNetTestContext'.\r\nSystem.InvalidOperationException: The required column 'extra_field' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Sql.Internal.FromSqlNonComposedQuerySqlGenerator.CreateValueBufferFactory(IRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory relationalValueBufferFactoryFactory, DbDataReader dataReader)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ShaperCommandContext.<NotifyReaderCreated>b__11_0(FactoryAndReader s)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.NonCapturingLazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized[TParam,TValue](TValue& target, TParam param, Func`2 valueFactory)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ShaperCommandContext.NotifyReaderCreated(DbDataReader dataReader)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(Boolean buffer)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<CompileQueryCore>b__0(QueryContext qc)","hasFullStack":true,"parsedStack":[{"level":0,"method":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Sql.Internal.FromSqlNonComposedQuerySqlGenerator.CreateValueBufferFactory","assembly":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60"},{"level":1,"method":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ShaperCommandContext.<NotifyReaderCreated>b__11_0","assembly":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60"},{"level":2,"method":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.NonCapturingLazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized","assembly":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60"},{"level":3,"method":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ShaperCommandContext.NotifyReaderCreated","assembly":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60"},{"level":4,"method":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1+Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext","assembly":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60"},{"level":5,"method":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute","assembly":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60"},{"level":6,"method":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1+Enumerator.MoveNext","assembly":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60"},{"level":7,"method":"System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault","assembly":"System.Linq, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"},{"level":8,"method":"lambda_method","assembly":"Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"},{"level":9,"method":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler+<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<CompileQueryCore>b__0","assembly":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60"}]}],"severityLevel":"Error"}}}
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Error: An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query for context type 'WebApiAureliaCli.Models.VsNetTestContext'.
System.InvalidOperationException: The required column 'extra_field' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Sql.Internal.FromSqlNonComposedQuerySqlGenerator.CreateValueBufferFactory(IRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory relationalValueBufferFactoryFactory, DbDataReader dataReader)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ShaperCommandContext.<NotifyReaderCreated>b__11_0(FactoryAndReader s)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.NonCapturingLazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized[TParam, TValue](TValue& target, TParam param, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ShaperCommandContext.NotifyReaderCreated(DbDataReader dataReader)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(Boolean buffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState, TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<CompileQueryCore>b__0(QueryContext qc)

System.InvalidOperationException: The required column 'extra_field' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Sql.Internal.FromSqlNonComposedQuerySqlGenerator.CreateValueBufferFactory(IRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory relationalValueBufferFactoryFactory, DbDataReader dataReader)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ShaperCommandContext.<NotifyReaderCreated>b__11_0(FactoryAndReader s)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.NonCapturingLazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized[TParam, TValue](TValue& target, TParam param, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ShaperCommandContext.NotifyReaderCreated(DbDataReader dataReader)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(Boolean buffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState, TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<CompileQueryCore>b__0(QueryContext qc)
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
Log Error: Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
Object name: 'VsNetTestContext'.
Application Insights Telemetry(unconfigured): { "name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2017-09-21T11:56:49.6463034Z","tags":{ "ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.1.1","ai.internal.nodeName":"CTAPLAPTOP4","ai.operation.id":"a52ef379-4f366ebbd2a82b55","ai.operation.name":"GET Clients/Get [id/nav]","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"CTAPLAPTOP4","ai.operation.parentId":"|a52ef379-4f366ebbd2a82b55.","ai.location.ip":"127.0.0.1"},"data":{ "baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{ "ver":2,"message":"Executing ObjectResult, writing value Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext.","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{ "DeveloperMode":"true","CategoryName":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ObjectResultExecutor","{OriginalFormat}":"Executing ObjectResult, writing value {Value}.","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","Value":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext"} } } }
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ObjectResultExecutor:Information: Executing ObjectResult, writing value Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext.
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): { "name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2017-09-21T11:56:49.6559626Z","tags":{ "ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.1.1","ai.internal.nodeName":"CTAPLAPTOP4","ai.operation.id":"a52ef379-4f366ebbd2a82b55","ai.operation.name":"GET Clients/Get [id/nav]","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"CTAPLAPTOP4","ai.operation.parentId":"|a52ef379-4f366ebbd2a82b55.","ai.location.ip":"127.0.0.1"},"data":{ "baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{ "ver":2,"message":"Executed action WebApiAureliaCli.Controllers.ClientsController.Get (WebApiAureliaCliWebpack) in 375.9021ms","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{ "DeveloperMode":"true","CategoryName":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker","ElapsedMilliseconds":"375.9021","{OriginalFormat}":"Executed action {ActionName} in {ElapsedMilliseconds}ms","ActionName":"WebApiAureliaCli.Controllers.ClientsController.Get (WebApiAureliaCliWebpack)","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development"} } } }
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action WebApiAureliaCli.Controllers.ClientsController.Get(WebApiAureliaCliWebpack) in 375.9021ms
Application Insights Telemetry(unconfigured): { "name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2017-09-21T11:56:49.6666798Z","tags":{ "ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.1.1","ai.internal.nodeName":"CTAPLAPTOP4","ai.operation.id":"a52ef379-4f366ebbd2a82b55","ai.operation.name":"GET Clients/Get [id/nav]","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"CTAPLAPTOP4","ai.operation.parentId":"|a52ef379-4f366ebbd2a82b55.","ai.location.ip":"127.0.0.1"},"data":{ "baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{ "ver":2,"message":"Request finished in 403.6099ms 500 application/json; charset=utf-8","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{ "DeveloperMode":"true","CategoryName":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost","ElapsedMilliseconds":"403.6099","ContentType":"application/json; charset=utf-8","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","StatusCode":"500"} } } }
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 403.6099ms 500 application/json; charset=utf-8
Application Insights Telemetry(unconfigured): { "name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Request","time":"2017-09-21T11:56:49.2629283Z","tags":{ "ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.1.1","ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.internal.nodeName":"CTAPLAPTOP4","ai.operation.id":"a52ef379-4f366ebbd2a82b55","ai.operation.name":"GET Clients/Get [id/nav]","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"CTAPLAPTOP4","ai.location.ip":"127.0.0.1"},"data":{ "baseType":"RequestData","baseData":{ "ver":2,"id":"|a52ef379-4f366ebbd2a82b55.","name":"GET Clients/Get [id/nav]","duration":"00:00:00.4130153","success":false,"responseCode":"500","url":"http://localhost:5813/api/clients/1/","properties":{ "DeveloperMode":"true","httpMethod":"GET","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development"} } } }
```

Clearly I am not disposing the context in any way. Why am I getting the disposed object error on my context? This seems like a reasonable approach to catching and tracking exceptions.

EDIT: I should mention that if I remove the exception handling, the 500 response has nothing in it about the exception that occurred.  So, no way to find out what went wrong on either the server or the client.

Answer (score 1):

The default lifetime for 'DbContext' is Scope which means that the lifetime is the duration of a request.  Since you're setting the singleton's property only when it is not set, it retains the DbContext from the first request made to a controller that sets the property and never gets a new one.  This DbContext instance is disposed of after that first request completes.

My suggestion is don't use a singleton exception handler; register the exception handler with the DI container with a scoped lifetime (which will allow it to obtain the DbContext instance via DI).

Comment: How do I "register the exception handler with the DI container"?

Comment: In the `ConfigureServices` method of the `Startup` class; see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection

Comment: I did that and now I have a different error: `There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.`  This happens on the ExecuteSqlCommand.  Shouldn't it be a different connection?  I'm injecting the exception handler into my controller along with the dbcontext.  The exception handler has its own injected dbcontext.

Comment: The same DbContext instance is injected into both your controller and your error handler.  Try enabling MultipleAvtiveResultSets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets

Comment: Why isn't the reader closed when the exception occurs?  Is there a way to manually close all readers, say in the catch block?

Comment: After reading the details of MARS I'm not sure it is a good choice for Web API.  Back to my previous comment, why is the reader left open after an exception and how can one close it?  Is there a better way to track the details of an exception?

Comment: I suppose one could manually create a second SqlConnection and execute the exception logging on that connection.

Comment: You can always create a new DbContext instance.  Why do you hesitate to enable MARS?

Comment: When I attempted to create a new DbContext I received a message that it was not intended to be created in code or some such thing.  I've been using SQL Server since 1991....I know, it only ran on OS2... and have never had this issue.  In .NET using DataAdapters, and LINQ to SQL it was never an issue.  I think the issue with EFCore is it is trying to do everything with a single connection, which is leading to these issues.  MARS just masks the initial problem and has inefficiencies and limitations that I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by opening a new connection the old way. This enables me to trap the original exception in the Web API controller and log it to the database:

```
public static void Log()
{
    //Writes exception data to the database
    try
    {
          using (var cn = new SqlConnection(DbConnectionString))
          {
                cn.Open();
                var cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "dbo.LogApplicationError";
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@err_title", mcErrTitle);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@err_message", mcErrMsg);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@err_description", mcErrDescription);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@app_name", "OIO");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@app_version", "1.0");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_name", "");
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
          //ignore
          System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Log Exception: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```